# Парсинг xml sql

Tags: sql, парсер, sql-server, xml, xquery

Помогите распарсить подобный хмл, не могу понять как правильно определить ноду и путь

```
declare @bxml nvarchar(max)
set @bxml = '    
<kk:Текст xmlns:kk="http://адрес" xmlns="http://адрес2" xmlns:kk3="http://адрес3" xmlns:kk4="http://адрес4" xmlns:kk5="адрес5">
    <kk:Раздел>
        <kk:Запрос>
            <Дата xmlns="http://адрес2">1900-03-03</Дата>
            <Номер xmlns="http://адрес2">999-999</Номер>
        </kk:Запрос>
        <kk:Номер>555-555</kk:Номер>
        <kk:Свед>1900-01-01</kk:Свед>
        <kk:Дата>1900-02-02</kk:Дата>
    </kk:Раздел>
</kk:Текст>
'

select 
[Номер]  =  T.c.value('declare namespace PD="http://адрес2"; (./PD:Номер)[1]','varchar(50)')
from (select bxml = convert(xml, @bxml) ) xx
    cross apply
           xx.bxml.nodes('declare namespace PD="http://адрес2"; /PD:Текст/PD:Запрос') T(c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Я предполагаю, что это MS SQL Server.

Лучше использовать тип данных `XML` вместо `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<kk:Текст xmlns:kk="http://адрес" xmlns="http://адрес2" xmlns:kk3="http://адрес3" xmlns:kk4="http://адрес4">
    <kk:Раздел>
        <kk:Запрос>
            <Дата xmlns="http://адрес2">1900-03-03</Дата>
            <Номер xmlns="http://адрес2">999-999</Номер>
        </kk:Запрос>
        <kk:Номер>555-555</kk:Номер>
        <kk:Свед>1900-01-01</kk:Свед>
        <kk:Дата>1900-02-02</kk:Дата>
    </kk:Раздел>
</kk:Текст>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://адрес' AS kk, DEFAULT 'http://адрес2') 
SELECT [Запрос_Дата]  =  c.value(N'(kk:Запрос/Дата/text())[1]','DATE')
    , [Запрос_Номер]  =  c.value(N'(kk:Запрос/Номер/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)')
    , [Номер]  =  c.value(N'(kk:Номер/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)')
    , [Дата]  =  c.value(N'(kk:Дата/text())[1]','DATE')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/kk:Текст/kk:Раздел') AS t(c);
```

**Результат**

| Запрос_Дата | Запрос_Номер | Номер | Дата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1900-03-03 | 999-999 | 555-555 | 1900-02-02 |